Calling another .py from the converted .exe file
I just want to ask how I can call another .py from the converted .exe file?
I have a main Python code called main_2.py file that acts as the main interface for the program that I created, which in this case, is the one that will be converted into .exe. One of its main functions is to open up another python code called analysis.py which in this case, is another GUI itself that will do other tasks.
My question is, can the convert .exe file called the .py directly, or should I convert the analysis.py into .exe as well?

Welcome to StackOverflow! If my answer did the trick, please mark it as resolved! It will help more people find a solution!

It's best to make a exe standalone without need for separate script files. Most tools for creating exes should be able to find imported scripts automatically and bundled into single exe. There is no need for 2 exe files.

It should be enough to import the functions from the second file, as explained here!
After that, auto-py-to-exe will automatically create an exe file with everything included needed to run it!
Another way is to add other py scripts as additional files!

Sorry for the late reply, after several trial and error I finally figured out what you mean and how it works. basically I just have to make sure the location of the .py code is properly call in order for it to works!
Thanks!

No problem! Glad it helped! Have a nice day
